# How to construct cardinal spline bases

Tags: splines, basis-function

I would like to know how to algebraically construct **cardinal** spline bases, as I would like to make a prediction with a natural cubic spline model which uses them; however, the only source I have found is [Simon Wood (2017)](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood), which I do not have access to.

I am familiar with the construction of truncated power series bases and B-spline bases, but not cardinal spline bases. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching, I found the definition here:

[https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~speleers/cime2017/material/notes_lyche.pdf](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Espeleers/cime2017/material/notes_lyche.pdf):

The function $M_p := B[0,1, . . . , p+ 1]$ is the cardinal B-spline of
degree p, and it is defined recursively as follows:

$$M_p(x) = \frac{x}{p} M_{p−1}(x) + \frac{p + 1 − x}{p} M_{p−1}(x−1), \quad p ≥ 1$$

$$\text{where}$$

$$M_0(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \in [0, 1)$,} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$